# data at the root level is invalid. line 1 position 1 in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to commit a document to a specific service. The document is in .doc format. I have to convert it to .pdf then create an xml to the created pdf document then commit the XML document. 
This is my code:

```
 public string CommitDocumentToRepository(string extension, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        //Convert to PDF
        byte[] loPDFFileBytes;

        ConversionService.ContentResponse loResponse = new DocumentAdapter.ConversionService.ContentResponse();

        using (ConversionService.CustomPDFSoapClient loConversionServiceClient = new DocumentAdapter.ConversionService.CustomPDFSoapClient())
        {
            loResponse = loConversionServiceClient.OfficeToPDFContent(fileBytes, extension);
            loPDFFileBytes = loResponse.ContentPDF;
        }

        if (loPDFFileBytes != null)
        {
            xform loDocContainer = new xform();
            xformInstance loDocProperties = new xformInstance();

            loDocProperties.FIRST_NAME= this.FirstName;
            loDocProperties.LAST_NAME= this.LastName;
            loDocProperties.SEX = this.Sex;


            loDocContainer.instance = loDocProperties;

            string lsTempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
            string lsXMLofProperties = loDocContainer.Serialize();

            XmlDocument loDoc = new XmlDocument();


            loDoc.LoadXml(lsXMLofProperties);
            loDoc.Save(lsTempFile);

            byte[] loFilePropertiesXML = Common.StreamFile(lsTempFile);
            string lsReturnValue = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                using (ISCommittalService.CommittalSoapClient loCommittalServiceClient = new DocumentAdapter.ISCommittalService.CommittalSoapClient())
                {
                    lsReturnValue = loCommittalServiceClient.CommitDocumentByte(loPDFFileBytes, ".PDF", loFilePropertiesXML);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception loException)
            {
                ADConnectionException loConnectionException = new ADConnectionException(loException);
                throw loException;
            }

            return lsReturnValue;
        }
        else
            return string.Empty;


    }
```

I'm getting this error "server was unable to process request. ---> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." from the method CommitDocumentByte.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xform xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<instance>

<FIRST_NAME xsi:type="xsd:string">JOHN</FIRST_NAME>
<LAST_NAME xsi:type="xsd:string">DOE</LAST_NAME>

</instance>
</xform>
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Comment: Usually an error at (1,1) indicates there is no XML at all in the buffer, e.g. the transaction to retrieve the XML failed.

Comment: @JohnWu I'm able to save the XML file and retrieve it because I can read the bytes of the saved file. I think if the transaction to retrieve the XML has failed I wouldn't be able to get the bytes of the file, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

> The document is in .doc format.

DOC files are not XML; you cannot parse them with an XML parser.

DOCX files are XML (OOXML), but only after extracting them from their Open Packaging Convention wrapping.

The XML you go on to post is neither DOC nor DOCX.  If you're getting a line 1 position 1 error on that file, first make absolutely sure that it is indeed that file that you're sending to the parser and not an empty buffer/string or some other non-XML document.  Then make sure that you have the character encoding set properly.  (Are you sure it's utf-16 and not utf-8?)

Comment: The original document is .doc but I converted it to .pdf then to XML file and I posted the XML file that I'm trying to upload but I agree with you that I have a doubt that maybe the problem is with the encoding.  that first line was added by itslef using xmlDocument. Do you have an idea how to change it from utf-16 to utf-8?

Comment: I tried with the example in the link that you suggested but it gives me the same error message. data at the root level is invalid. line 1 position 1

Comment: Show us a ***hex dump*** of the ***exact*** (log and check immediately before parsing -- don't assume that the file on disk being read earlier is what's being parsed) data that's being given to the parser.

Comment: the XML file that I shared in the post is what I get immediately before parsing

Comment: Prove it by posting the code the logs the output, and show us a ***hex dump*** of the data.